# Train Composition from testdome in python

Tags: python

The problem is as follows

> A TrainComposition is built by attaching and detaching wagons from the
>   left and the right sides, efficiently with respect to time used.
>
> For example, if we start by attaching wagon 7 from the left followed
>   by attaching wagon 13, again from the left, we get a composition of
>   two wagons (13 and 7 from left to right). Now the first wagon that can
>   be detached from the right is 7 and the first that can be detached
>   from the left is 13.
>
> Implement a TrainComposition that models this problem.

My code is below and it runs correctly but it fails for  ***Performance test with a large number of wagons: Time limit exceeded*** should I not use the library collection? and do the detach with `del(index)`?

```py
from collections import deque
test_list = deque([])
class TrainComposition:

    def __init__(self):
        pass   

    def attach_wagon_from_left(self, wagonId):

        test_list.appendleft(wagonId) 
        #mylist.insert(0,wagonId)
        print(test_list)
    def attach_wagon_from_right(self, wagonId):

        test_list.append(wagonId)

    def detach_wagon_from_left(self):
        if len(test_list)==0: 
            print('no more carts')
        else:
            value=test_list[0]
            test_list.popleft()
            return value 


    def detach_wagon_from_right(self):
        if len(test_list)==0:
           print('no more carts')
        else:
            value=test_list[len(test_list)-1]
            test_list.pop()
            return value 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train = TrainComposition()
    train.attach_wagon_from_left(7)
    train.attach_wagon_from_left(13)
    print(train.detach_wagon_from_right()) # should print 7
    print(train.detach_wagon_from_left()) # should print 13
    print(train.detach_wagon_from_right())
```

Comment: There's a lot of missing information in your problem statement.  Can you at least provide meaningful input and expected output.  Preferably an example of the attaching/detaching process and constraints around it that relate to time.

Comment: for more information see the problem statement from the original site   https://www.testdome.com/questions/python/train-composition/40609

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea using deque to do this but your implementation didn't leverage the object's benefits.

Two things are slowing it down:

- using len(test_list) will need to go through the whole linked list to count item  causing an O(n) time complexity
- Accessing test_list at a specific index is also an O(n) operation unless the index is zero (for the first item) or -1 (for the last item)

The deque object provides the mechanisms to avoid these two usages for the use case you a re trying to implement:

- Checking if the queue is empty : `if not test_list: ...`
- getting the 1st or last item: `test_list[0]` or `test_list[-1]`
- Also, pop() and popleft() return the item that was removed so you don't even need to access them beforehand

So the whole class could have been written with one line mapping to deque methods:

```
from collections import deque 
class TrainComposition:

    def __init__(self):
        self.wagons     = deque()

    def attach_wagon_from_left(self, wagonId):
        self.wagons.insert(0,wagonId)

    def attach_wagon_from_right(self, wagonId):
        self.wagons.append(wagonId)

    def detach_wagon_from_left(self):
        return self.wagons.popleft() if self.wagons else None

    def detach_wagon_from_right(self):
        return self.wagons.pop() if self.wagons else None
```

If you don't want to use deque (or are not allowed), you could also implement this using a dictionary as internal structure:

```
class TrainComposition:

    def __init__(self):
        self.wagons = dict()
        self.left  = 1
        self.right = 0

    def attach_wagon_from_left(self, wagonId):
        self.left -= 1
        self.wagons[self.left] = wagonId

    def attach_wagon_from_right(self, wagonId):
        self.right += 1
        self.wagons[self.right] = wagonId

    def detach_wagon_from_left(self):
        if self.left>self.right: return None
        wagonId = self.wagons[self.left]
        del self.wagons[self.left]
        self.left += 1
        return wagonId

    def detach_wagon_from_right(self):
        if self.left>self.right: return None
        wagonId = self.wagons[self.right]
        del self.wagons[self.right]
        self.right -= 1
        return wagonId
```